# Media Play/Pause Simulation

Tags: python, windows

My keyboard contains a row of buttons for various non-standard keyboard tasks. These keys contain such functions as modifying the volume, playing or pausing, and skipping tracks. How can I simulate a basic play/pause with Python? I am on Windows, by the way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use [pywin32](http://starship.python.net/crew/mhammond/win32/Downloads.html). Bundled with the installation is a large number of API-docs (usually placed at something like `C:\Python32\Lib\site-packages`.) It essentially wraps a lot of stuff in the Win32-library which is used for many low-levels tasks in Windows.

After installing it you could use the wrapper for [keybd_event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646304.aspx).

*You could also use `SendInput` instead of `keybd_event` but it doesn't seem to be wrapped by PyWin32. `SendMessage` is also an option but more cumbersome.*

You'll need to look up the virtual scan code for those special buttons, since I doubt the char-to-code mapping functions will help you here. You can find the reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731.aspx).

Then it is a simple matter of calling the function. The snippet below pauses Chuck Berry on my computer.

```
>>> import win32api
>>> VK_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE = 0xB3
>>> hwcode = win32api.MapVirtualKey(VK_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE, 0)
>>> hwcode
34
>>> win32api.keybd_event(VK_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE, hwcode)
```

`MapVirtualKey` gives us the hardware scan code which `keybd_event` needs (or more likely, the keyboard driver.)

Note that all this is snapped up by the keyboard driver, so you don't really have any control where the keystrokes are sent. With `SendMessage` you can send them to a specific window. It usually doesn't matter with media keys since those are intercepted by music players and such.

Comment: It should be noted that the scan code produced by MapVirtualKey is incorrect or incomplete, but it generally does not matter because most applications do not care what the scan code is (you could simply pass 0).  Scan code 34 is the 'G' key.  The correct scan code for Play/Pause has the 0xE0 prefix byte, meaning that the `KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY` flag should be passed to MapVirtualKey.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pyautogui`. This library contains a lot of keyboard and mouse simulations.
To install run `pip install pyautogui` in cmd.

In order to simulate a play/pause keypress, you should use `pyautogui.press("playpause")`.

Check out their docs at https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html to see the list of the supported keys and some other keyboard functions.

Answer (score 0):

This was not working for me on Windows 10 64, all recent updates installed.  I needed this (the 3rd parameter 2) before it'd work.

```
win32api.keybd_event(0xB3,0,2,0)
```

didn't bother looking into **why** it works, but threw it out there since this and other similar posts had me frustrated as for some reason not working on my PC.

This successfully paused/played Amazon Music on my PC.