# Python pywin32 - VK_SLEEP press not working

Tags: python, keyboard, pywin32

I found this solution for pressing virtual keys: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10441322/3448364
But, problem is that VK_SLEEP not working for me. I tried with all other VK_ keys (like VK_VOLUME_UP, VK_MEDIA_NEXT_TRACK...) and it works, only VK_SLEEP not working.
This is my code:

```
VK_SLEEP = 0x5F
hwcode = win32api.MapVirtualKey(VK_SLEEP, 0)
win32api.keybd_event(VK_SLEEP, hwcode)
```

When I execute that code, nothig happens. When I change virtual key to ie. VK_VOLUME_UP: works like a charm! So, code is OK, but for some reason script won't put PC in sleep with VK_SLEEP.
This is source for VK_ codes that I use: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/virtual-key-codes

Just to be clear: my keyboard doesn't have dedicated Sleep button. But, doesn't have "volume up" too, and 0xAF (vlume_up) works. So, I don't think problem is keyboard (it's CM MK750).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simulating `VK_SLEEP` will not have any effect, probably for security reasons.

Changing the systems's power state requires `SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME` privileges. If privileges is changed successfully, you can use [`SetSuspendState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/powrprof/nf-powrprof-setsuspendstate) to put the computer to sleep.

```
import win32api
import win32security
import ctypes

def sleep_mode():
    access = (win32security.TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | win32security.TOKEN_QUERY)
    htoken = win32security.OpenProcessToken(win32api.GetCurrentProcess(), access)
    if htoken:
        priv_id = win32security.LookupPrivilegeValue(None, win32security.SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME)
        win32security.AdjustTokenPrivileges(htoken, 0,
            [(priv_id, win32security.SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED)])
        ctypes.windll.powrprof.SetSuspendState(False, True, True)
        win32api.CloseHandle(htoken)

sleep_mode()
```

Side note,

`keybd_event` pushes the key down. Make sure the key is pushed back up. Example:

```
import win32api
import win32con

win32api.keybd_event(win32con.VK_VOLUME_UP, 0)
win32api.keybd_event(win32con.VK_VOLUME_UP, 0, win32con.KEYEVENTF_KEYUP)
```

Comment: Edit: only problem is that PC wake up immediately after I put it in sleep. There is no problem if I put PC in sleep in classic way (Start menu), only with this script.

Comment: That's odd. The second parameter in `SetSuspendState` should disable wake timers as stated in MS documentation. What is your OS?

Comment: Windows 10. I'll test more. I found some oslution online for waking PC from sleep.

Comment: Great answer, thanks a lot. What is the correct `SetSuspendState` tho?

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37009899/8344913). It says that sleep should be False, True, False. Altough that according to the MS documentation you are right.

Comment: @DanielReyhanian The other answer is not wrong. You can set the third parameter to false if you don't want to disable wake events, for example the anti-virus can wake up the computer to run scans. Or use `False, True, False` if you want sleep without wake events.