# Reliably pause all playing media on Windows

Tags: windows, media, playback, pause

I am setting up a plugin for KDE Connect where I pause any playing media as and when I get a call on my phone. For the Windows build of this plugin, I am currently using VK_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE. Is there some instruction(s) I can use to simply PAUSE or simply PLAY the media? That is, not a toggle, instruction(s) with "only one" of the two behaviours?
IF not, is there some other way I can reliably determine if there is any media playing on my system?

I have read [Media Play/Pause Simulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10441110/media-play-pause-simulation) . but a toggle is not reliable in my use case.

Answer (score 0):

[`WM_APPCOMMAND`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-appcommand) has `APPCOMMAND_MEDIA_PAUSE`. Send it directly to a player if you know its `HWND` or send it to yourself and let `DefWindowProc` turn it into a shell hook event.

Comment: I need to use the solution to pause ANY playing media on my system, my software does not play any media itself, but I want to control all other playing media and pause them if possible. Could you help me with a short code snippet as well?

Comment: it seems DefWindowProc is used to "handle" a particular event. I am handling the call part already, I just need a reliable replacement for VK_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE. I'm sorry, but I didn't get how your answer helps me in that :/
Could you please elaborate, if I am wrong? (I really hope I am wrong, because I don't got much Windows development experience)

Comment: A media player can handle WM_APPCOMMAND directly. Normally, if the foreground window does not handle WM_APPCOMMAND the message is converted to a shell event by DefWindowProc. It is up to the player (and any other software) to listen for this shell event. Most player probably don't and only care when they are the foreground window and get the message instead of the event. Therefore you need to send a message to every player you care about.

Comment: how do I get the list of players?

Comment: There is no list, you have to make your own database of window class names.